# Doing the ls output magic in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I want to have the same output as ls creates in a bash or python script.
I don't mean listing directories, but the thing ls does to be able to be "loopable". Example:

```
# ls
a b c d

# ls | head -n 1
a

# for i in $(ls); do echo "file: $i"; done
file: a
file: b
file: c
file: d
```

How can ls be like that and still display everything in one line when calling it?

Using tabs doesn't work.. Newlines just force it to be multiple lines. \000 doesn't work.

```
# echo -e "a\tb\tc\td" | head -n 1
a    b    c    d

echo -e "a\000b\000c\000d" | head -n 1
abcd
```

cat -A doesn't give me much info...

```
# cat -A <(ls --color=no)
a$
b$
c$
d$

# cat -A <(echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd")
a$
b$
c$
d$
```

So.. How can I generate the same type of output does in my scripts? Is there any control characters I am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is to detect whether the output is a terminal, in which case `ls` uses columns, or not, in which case it outputs in a simpler format.

In Unix, you should be able to use Python's `os.isatty()` function to get this information.

From the shell, you can use the `tty(1)` program: `tty -s <&1`. This will exit true if stdout is a tty, and false if it is not. `tty` actually checks stdin, but with `<&1` you can redirect stdout to stdin to effectively check stdout.

Comment: ohh, great. Is there a bash version of this too? Creating a little test script, then accepting your solution.

Comment: FWIW, I know the question specifically asked about Linux, but `os.isatty(1)` works just fine on Windows too.

Comment: @camh: That's fine for shells other than Bash, but Bash can do the check without invoking an external utility.

Answer (score 4):

First answer accepted, but here is a complete example..

cat test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

if os.isatty(1):
    print 'is tty'
else:
    print 'is script'
```

And the output:

```
# python test.py
is tty

# python test.py | tail -n 1
is script
```

Answer (score 3):

In Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -p /dev/stdout || ! -t 1 ]]    # output is to a pipe or redirected
then
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
else                                 # output is to the terminal
    printf '%s' "$*"
    printf '\n'
fi
```

FYI: use `for i in *` instead of `for i in $(ls)`

Comment: What is the purpose of testing if stdout is a named pipe? Is it not sufficient to just check if it is a terminal?

Comment: @camh: It illustrates that it's possible to do other combinations. Of course `if [[ -t 1 ]]` and swapping the actions will work just fine.